# How to move a key value in a dictionary list one level up in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, scripting

Using Python3, I'm trying to move on key value pair in a dictionary list up on level.

I have a variable called product that has the following:

```
    [ 
    {'color': 'red', 
     'shape': 'round', 
     'extra': {'price': 'large', 
               'onsale': 'yes',
               'instock: 'yes'}
    }, 
    {'color': 'blue', 
     'shape': 'square', 
     'extra': {'price': 'small', 
               'onsale': 'no',
               'instock: 'yes'}
    }
    ]
```

I'd like to move the key value pair of "instock" within extra up one level, to be on par with color, shape, extra - so this:

```
    [ 
    {'color': 'red', 
     'shape': 'round', 
     'extra': {'price': 'large', 
               'instock: 'yes'},
     'onsale': 'yes'
    }, 
    {'color': 'blue', 
     'shape': 'square', 
     'extra': {'price': 'small', 
               'onsale': 'no'},
     'instock: 'yes'
    }
    ]
```

I tried playing with the following code that I found here:

```
    result = {}
    for i in products:
        if i["href"] not in result:
            result[i["selection_id"]] = {'selection_id': i["selection_id"], 'other_data':                         i["other_data"], 'value_dict': []}
        result[i["selection_id"]]["value_dict"].append({'value': i["value"], "value_name": i["value_name"]})
```

It didn't work for me.

Any help or additional literature that I can find online would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"It didn't work"_ Why not, what went wrong? Did you not get the desired output? Did the code not run at all? Did you get an error halfway through? When you're asking for debugging help, the more relevant details you provide, the better.

Comment: For starters, it gives me a KeyError: 'onsale'. But as the code above shows, I have the onsale in the list.  Secondly, this code I found is the solution provided to a similar ask that I found, not exactly what I was looking for but I figured it was a good starter point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: iterate through the list.  For each dict, copy "extra"."instock" up one level and delete the original:

```
for outer_dict in product:
    outer_dict["instock"] = outer_dict["extra"]["instock"]
    del outer_dict["extra"]["instock"]

for outer_dict in product:
    print(outer_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'color': 'red', 'shape': 'round', 'extra': {'price': 'large', 'onsale': 'yes'}, 'instock': 'yes'}
{'color': 'blue', 'shape': 'square', 'extra': {'price': 'small', 'onsale': 'no'}, 'instock': 'yes'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [ 
    {'color': 'red', 
     'shape': 'round', 
     'extra': {'price': 'large', 
               'onsale': 'yes',
               'instock': 'yes'}
    }, 
    {'color': 'blue', 
     'shape': 'square', 
     'extra': {'price': 'small', 
               'onsale': 'no',
               'instock': 'yes'}
    }
]

for d in lst:
    d['instock'] = d['extra'].pop('instock')

# pretty print on screen:
from pprint import pprint
pprint(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[{'color': 'red',
  'extra': {'onsale': 'yes', 'price': 'large'},
  'instock': 'yes',
  'shape': 'round'},
 {'color': 'blue',
  'extra': {'onsale': 'no', 'price': 'small'},
  'instock': 'yes',
  'shape': 'square'}]
```

---

Or you could use:

```
d['extra'].pop('instock', 'no')
```

in case there's no `instock` key (the default value is `no` in this case)

Answer (score 0):

```
products = [
    {'color': 'red', 
     'shape': 'round', 
     'extra': {'price': 'large', 
               'onsale': 'yes',
               'instock': 'yes'}
    }, 
    {'color': 'blue', 
     'shape': 'square', 
     'extra': {'price': 'small', 
               'onsale': 'no',
               'instock': 'yes'}
    }
    ]
    
    
result_list = []    
result = {}
    
for item in products:
    for key,values in item.items():
        if isinstance(values,dict):
            for inner_key, inner_value in values.items():
                #remove me if you want all of the inner items to level-up
                if inner_key == "instock":
                    result[inner_key] = inner_value
        else:
            result[key] = values
            
    result_list.append(result)


print (result_list)
```

output:

```
[{'color': 'blue', 'shape': 'square', 'instock': 'yes'}, {'color': 'blue', 'shape': 'square', 'instock': 'yes'}]
```

added comment to clarify where to modify in case you want other key to be level-up as well

Comment: Hello, this almost worked - it didn't include the first one (color:blue) vs both (color:blue) and (color;red) I would have expected both elements to be updated.

Comment: that's because the keys in dictionary is unique. insert each one of them as a list item solved it